Livecharts crashing whenever ScalesYAt != 0
I'm using LiveChartsCore 2.0.0-rc2 together with the .SkiaSharpView and .SkiaSharpView.WinForms (also the same 2.0.0-rc2 version)
I'm trying to create a multiple axis Vertical Axis graph such as 
For simplification I'm trying to use only the blue and red lines:
 public partial class ViewModelMultiple2 : ObservableObject
   {
       public ViewModelMultiple2()
       {

           var blue = new SKColor(25, 118, 210);
           var red = new SKColor(229, 57, 53);

           Series = new ObservableCollection<ISeries>
               {
                   new LineSeries<double>
                   {
                       LineSmoothness = 1,
                       Name = "tens",
                       Values = new ObservableCollection<double> { 14, 13, 14, 15, 17 },
                       Stroke = new SolidColorPaint(blue, 2),
                       GeometryStroke = new SolidColorPaint(blue, 2),
                       Fill = null,
                       ScalesYAt = 0
                   },
                   new LineSeries<double>
                   {
                       Name = "tens 2",
                       Values = new ObservableCollection<double> { 11, 12, 13, 10, 13 },
                       Stroke = new SolidColorPaint(blue, 2),
                       GeometryStroke = new SolidColorPaint(blue, 2),
                       Fill = null,
                       ScalesYAt = 0
                   },
                   new LineSeries<double>
                   {
                       Name = "hundreds",
                       Values = new ObservableCollection<double> { 533, 586, 425, 579, 518 },
                       Stroke = new SolidColorPaint(red, 2),
                       GeometryStroke = new SolidColorPaint(red, 2),
                       Fill = null,

                     //!!Here it crashes, unless I set it to 0
                       ScalesYAt = 1 
                   },
   
               };

           YAxes = new List<Axis>
           {
               {
                   LabelsPaint = new SolidColorPaint(blue)
               },
               {
                   LabelsPaint = new SolidColorPaint(red),
                   ShowSeparatorLines = false,
                   Position = LiveChartsCore.Measure.AxisPosition.End
               },
           };

       }
       public List<Axis> YAxes { get; set; }
       public ObservableCollection<ISeries> Series { get; set; }

   }

I'm then calling it in the Form1, with the click of a button (I think this might be the problem):
 public partial class Form1 : Form
   {

       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1300, 830);

}

private void Test2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

      var viewModelMultiple2 = new ViewModelMultiple2();
      var cartesianchart5 = new CartesianChart
      {
          XAxes = viewModelMultiple2.YAxes,

//!!When this series below is called, I get:

//This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
//Inner Exception 1:
//IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

          Series = viewModelMultiple2.Series,

          Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10),
          Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1100, 700),
          AutoSize = false

      };

      panel1.Controls.Add(cartesianchart5);
}
}

Does anyone have an idea why this could be a problem?
The best result I can have is with ScalesYAt = 0 for the red line


Found it,
Indeed its in the button call that the problem is
Basically there's a difference between XAxes, YAxes and Series..
  var cartesianchart4 = new CartesianChart
  {
      YAxes = viewModelMultiple2.YAxes,
      Series = viewModelMultiple2.Series,
      XAxes = viewModelMultiple2.XAxes,

  
  };

